# how to scale image with jquery

Tags: jquery, flash, image, image-resizing

What would be the best and fastest way to scale/resize an image which is injected into PHP file which is called via AJAX with use of jQuery?

So I am trying to assure the image does not bypass the width of 600px and height of 410px but I do not wish for the image to be maxing out this dimensions and look weird, it has to be displayed as it would be, but just in smaller scale.

Also if there is a way I can do this with a already existing Flash script that would be great, but I do not recall of any good ones which are as simple as one used by Google on there Picasaweb service.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Here is some `jQuery` that works:

```
var max_size = 200;
$("img").each(function(i) {
  if ($(this).height() > $(this).width()) {
    var h = max_size;
    var w = Math.ceil($(this).width() / $(this).height() * max_size);
  } else {
    var w = max_size;
    var h = Math.ceil($(this).height() / $(this).width() * max_size);
  }
  $(this).css({ height: h, width: w });
});
```

Check it out in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/QgDEk/

The original size of the image is huge but that script resizes it.

Here is the [tutorial](http://adeelejaz.com/blog/resize-images-on-fly-using-jquery/) on it.

Comment: What if you wanted a different max width and max height?

Comment: Change `max_size` to whatever you want. The OP wanted something that will resize their images without distorting it.

Comment: that works but i still on the verge of bashing my head into the keyboard it seems that when the app fetches images via JSON from Picasaweb there already resized for some one reason

Comment: Nathan, I know. However, your solution doesn't allow for a *different* max width and max height. Mine does, and still doesn't distort the image.

Comment: @PT Desu Are they already resized how you want them or do you want them to be resized differently?

Comment: @Nathan well there fetched by jQuery via JSON, but not sure whats going on since one time it works and next the image is 500x500px while its dimensions are 500x1000 or so. So i am personally lost, it seems like Picasa is messing with me, since it came to my attention today that 2 different image resizing script are failing one in JSP and 2nd in PHP and both having same problem while they worked great before

Answer (score 2):

The `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` DOM properties of an `HTMLImageElement` return the source image's real dimensions.

```
if (imageElement.naturalWidth > imageElement.naturalHeight)
    imageElement.style.width = '600px';
else
    imageElement.style.height = '410px';
```

- Landscape image example: http://jsbin.com/ogisej/13
- Portrait image example: http://jsbin.com/ogisej/14
- Square image example: http://jsbin.com/ogisej/15

Notice how in the examples, the resizing code is put in a `load` handler for the image, such that it only resizes it when the dimension information is available. Otherwise `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` are zero, which causes problems. If you are disconcerted by watching images start off big, then shrinking, hide the image by default and then show it after resizing:

- Landscape image example: http://jsbin.com/ogisej/17
- Portrait image example: http://jsbin.com/ogisej/18
- Square image example: http://jsbin.com/ogisej/19

No need for jQuery, nor Flash ;)

Comment: Your script works however there seems to be a problem, if an image is still being cached by the browser it will be injected into the Lightbox as its full size rather then being resized, if u close the lightbox and click same image again then its scaled down, but otherwise it will load as full.

Comment: My updated post has fixed that problem by wrapping the resizing in a `load` event handler for the image, such that it only tries to resize when the size information becomes available.

Comment: O thank you very much, well it seems I am complete retard I am not sure how but it seems the problem was being caused by the varialbe in JSON fetch string "&maxsize=500" which forced images to be displayed as 500x500px damm, how could this have happen and I rewrote so much god damm code because of this

Comment: tell me is there a way I can show say some sort of loading animation and only then insert the image? Instead of it being resized and only after its resized does it fit in the lightbox

Comment: You could combine my second example (that hides the image until ready to avoid a visual 'resizing'), with a loading spinner animation under the image.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with support for max width and height.

```
// Set max width and height
var maxHeight = 50,
    maxWidth = 40;

// Create new image
myImage = new Image();
myImage.src = 'http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff';

// On load of image
myImage.onload = function() {

    var width = myImage.width,
        height = myImage.height,
        ratio = Math.min(maxWidth / width, maxHeight / height);

    newWidth = parseInt(ratio * width);
    newHeight = parseInt(ratio * height);

    $('body').append('<p>Original: ' + width + ' x ' + height + '</p>');
    $('body').append('<p>Max: ' + maxWidth + ' x ' + maxHeight + '</p>');
    $('body').append('<p>Resized: ' + newWidth + ' x ' + newHeight + '</p>');

    // Add new image
    $('body').append($('<img>', {
        src: 'http://dummyimage.com/' + newWidth + 'x' + newHeight + '/000/fff',
        width: newWidth,
        height: newHeight,
        alt: "Test Image",
        title: "Test Image"
    }));
};
```